# Macos bundle app with Opencv and Mediapipe

Tags: python, macos, opencv, pyinstaller, mediapipe

I want to bundle my python code into a application (.app file) on MacOS.

`pyinstaller --noconsole --add-data="../v-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mediapipe/modules:mediapipe/modules"  main.py`

I have no errors in pyinstaller. The dist/main/main binary works correctly. But the dist/main.app, starts the program, raises a Tkinter window with a form. And when you press a button, it closes.

The main application after the Tkinter form has the cv2 and mediapipe libraries. I suspect it may be from there, but I can't find what could be failing.

Could anyone with experience building apps on macOS with Python help me?

Python 3.10.12
pyinstaller 5.13.0

main.spec:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(
    ['main.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[('../v-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mediapipe/modules', 'mediapipe/modules')],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    [],
    exclude_binaries=True,
    name='main',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    console=False,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
coll = COLLECT(
    exe,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    name='main',
)
app = BUNDLE(
    coll,
    name='main.app',
    icon=None,
    bundle_identifier=None,
)
```